# For Jesus' (as) miracles why does the Qur'an state "by God's permission"?

Tags: quran, prophets, prophet-isa, miracles, messengers

I don't recall for miracles of other Prophets or Messengers mentioned in the Qur'an that the text says "by God's permission" so why exclusively for Jesus (as)?

Comment: Probably to hammer in that he had no inherent power or divinity.

Comment: Can you provide an example of other miracles that are described by the prophets or messengers themselves without attributing the miracles to Allah (e.g., Yusuf attributing his miraculous knowledge to Allah in [12:37](https://quran.com/12/37) If you give examples, we can discuss each example on a case-by-case basis.

Comment: Salam and welcome to Islam SE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and model I strongly recommend you to take our [tour] and check our [help].Salam and welcome to Islam SE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and model I strongly recommend you to take our [tour] and check our [help].

Answer (score 2):

This is to make Muslims and Christians understand that Jesus(peace be upon him) is not God. Whatever miracles Jesus did was purely by God's help and permission.

Answer (score 0):

For the miracles of Jesus (pbuh), why does the Qur'an say "by the permission of God"?
All the miracles performed by the prophets were by the permission and command of God.
Because it was the place of the illusion that the people thought that Imam was independent in raising the dead, and therefore Jesus, after every miracle he announces, binds his word to the providence and permission of God Almighty. (1)

(1): Tabatabai, Mohammad Hussein, Al-Mizan Fi Tafsir Al-Quran, translated by Mousavi Hamedani, vol. 3, p. 312